# PUT Request in Axios, React, don't understand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im studying Axios with React and Redux and i tried to understand PUT request but its a little bit difficult to understand, can any one give me an example and describe its function to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PUT` is a standard HTTP verb, so this really isn't a React/Redux/Axios question. PUT either creates a new entity or completely replaces an existing entity. 
MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

There are two ways to write a `put` in axios - either

`axios.put(...)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

Or

```
axios({
  method: 'put',
  ...
})
```

The rest would be the same as what you'd do for a `post`

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: If you want to be more specified, how to write PUT request in Axios ?